# What does `.+` mean in value org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying mkyong spring [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-4-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/). Here is @RequestMapping usage:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

What does `.+` means? Is it regular expression for `name` PathVariable value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `name` in the value means the variable name that you put in the argument. the `.+` mean that the variable will accept one character or more.

example :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{textualPart:[a-z-]+}.{numericPart:[\\d]+}")
public String regularExpression(@PathVariable String textualPart,@PathVariable String numericPart)
```

Given the url - `/sometext.123`, the variable `textualPart` will have value `sometext` while the other variable will have value `123`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the regular expression and also the matching character(s) value will be assigned to the `name` variable for your to play with.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

means that all following URIs match:

- */hello/Jasmine*  - `name` will have Jasmine now
- */hello/Cherry*   - `name` will have Cherry now